# Creating a Map from a string based on the provided Keys when the string doesn't have delimiters in Java 8

Tags: java, regex, string, hashmap, java-stream

Given the following `String`:

```
String s = "DIMENSION 24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105"l x 74"w. CARE For best results, machine wash warm with like colors. COLOURS red blue green";
```

*Keys* are = `DIMENSIONS, DETAILED SPECIFICATION, CARE, COLOURS`

We need to create `Map<String,String>` where *keys* will be as provided above and corresponding text will be the *value*.

*The map's contents will look like:*

```
DIMENSION: 24cm 34cm 12cm,
DETAILED SPECIFICATION: Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105"l x 74"w,
CARE:  For best results, machine wash warm with like colors,
COLOURS: red blue green
```

And not necessary that all these *keys* and *values* are present in the string.

Suppose the *key* `CARE` is not present in the input `String`:

```
String s = "DIMENSION 24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105"l x 74"w. COLOURS red blue green";
```

*The map's contents will look like:*

```
DIMENSION: 24cm 34cm 12cm,
DETAILED SPECIFICATION: Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105"l x 74"w,
COLOURS: red blue green
```

I.e. if a *key* is absent in the given string then the corresponding *value* will be also absent. For instance, `DIMENSION` *key* is absent and string starts like `"DETAILED SPECIFICATION ... "`.

As the string doesn't have delimiters, I am unable to create a map from it.

With plane Java, I am able to do like this:

```
if(s.contains("ASSEMBLY")) {
    ass = s.substring(s.indexOf("COLOURS") + 8);
    s = s.replaceAll(s.substring(s.indexOf("COLOURS")),"");
}
if(s.contains("OVERALL")){
    ov = s.substring(s.indexOf("CARE") + 5);
    s = s.replaceAll(s.substring(s.indexOf("CARE")),"");
}
if(s.contains("CARE")){
    care1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("DETAILED SPECIFICATION") + 24);
    s = s.replaceAll(s.substring(s.indexOf("DETAILED SPECIFICATION")),"");
}
if(s.contains("DIMENSIONS")){
    de1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("DIMENSIONS") + 11);
    s =s.replaceAll(s.substring(s.indexOf("DIMENSIONS")),"");
}
```

If we have delimiter, then I am able to do it like this.

```
Map<String, String> map = Stream.of(s)
    .map(s -> s.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Comment: If a key value is not present, the string the processing should continue with whatever present without any error and add in the map for rest of the pairs.

Comment: That means each pair *key-value* is either present or not, correct? But there couldn't be the case when, for instance `DIMENSION` key is absent and string starts like that `"24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION ... "`?

Comment: No, if key is absent then value will be also absent. for instance DIMENSION key is absent then string starts like "DETAILED SPECIFICATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a regular expression from the given *keys* and compile it into a *pattern*.

I approached this problem using *lookahead* and *lookbehind*:

```
public static Pattern getPattern(Collection<String> keys) {
    String joinedKeys = String.join("|", keys);
    String regex = String.format("(?<=%s)|(?=%s)", joinedKeys, joinedKeys); // creates a regex "(?<=DIMENSION|DETAILED\\sSPECIFICATION|CARE|COLOURS)|(?=DIMENSION|DETAILED\\sSPECIFICATION|CARE|COLOURS)"
    return Pattern.compile(regex);
}
```

- `(?=foo)` - *Lookahead* - matches a position that immediately follows after the `foo`;
- `(?<=foo)` - *Lookbehind* - matches a position that immediately precedes the `foo`.

*For more information [have a look at this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*

When we have a *pattern*, we can generate a stream using [`Pattern.splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
public static Map<String, String> toMap(String source, Set<String> keys) {
    
    return getPattern(keys).splitAsStream(source)
        .collect(combineByKey(keys));
}
```

Each element of this a stream would be either a *key* or a *value*, and in order to obtain a *map* a result of the stream execution, we need a *collector* which will be capable to distinguish between a *key* from a *value*.

We can create such a *collector* using [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html). As its a *mutable container*, I'll use a `Deque` of *map-entries*.

A case with an *empty string* used as a *key* that can be observed in the *accumulator* function below represents a situation which might take place while executing the stream in parallel when a thread gets the piece of data which starts from a *value* and not from a *key*, in other words, a *key* and a *value* and up in different *containers*. This problem gets fixed when we're merging *containers* in the *combiner* function.

`StringBuilder` is used as an intermediate type of *value* an entry returned by `Map.entry()` is immutable.

*Note: `Map.entry()` was introduced with Java 9. To make this solution compliant with **Java 8** use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>()` instead ([see the code for JDK 8](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/stM)).*

```
public static Collector<String, ?, Map<String, String>> combineByKey(Set<String> keys) {

    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (Deque<Map.Entry<String, StringBuilder>> deque, String next) -> {
            if (keys.contains(next)) deque.add(Map.entry(next, new StringBuilder()));
            else {
                if (deque.isEmpty()) deque.add(Map.entry("", new StringBuilder(next)));
                else deque.getLast().getValue().append(next);
            }
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            if (!right.isEmpty() && !left.isEmpty() && right.getFirst().getKey().isEmpty()) {
                left.getLast().getValue().append(right.pollFirst().getValue());
            }
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
        },
        deque -> deque.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue().toString().strip()
        ))
    );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "DIMENSION 24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105l x 74w. CARE For best results, machine wash warm with like colors. COLOURS red blue green";

    Set<String> keys = Set.of("DIMENSION", "DETAILED SPECIFICATION", "CARE", "COLOURS");

    Map<String, String> result = toMap(source, keys); // converting the source string to map
    
    result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v)); // printing the result
}
```

*Output:*

```
COLOURS -> red blue green
DIMENSION -> 24cm 34cm 12cm
DETAILED SPECIFICATION -> Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105l x 74w.
CARE -> For best results, machine wash warm with like colors.
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/stM)

Comment: The way you example with look ahead and look behind pattern was good. My question was specific to java 8. If you can add one working example for java 8, then it would be good. Thanks @Alexander

Comment: @AjayKhetan Updated the answer. I've added the code fully compliant with JDK 8 to the [Online Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/stM) (the same link is present in the answer now) to avoid a need to copy the same method twice because differences are minor, and the latter approach is the preferred one.

Answer (score 3):

Regex approach:

```
    String s = "DIMENSION 24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105 w. COLOURS red blue green";
    String[] keys = new String[]{"DIMENSION", "DETAILED SPECIFICATION", "CARE", "COLOURS"};
    String keyRegex = String.join("|", keys);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<key>" + keyRegex + ") (?<value>((?!(" + keyRegex + ")).)*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        result.put(m.group("key"), m.group("value"));
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the regex you used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
String str = "DIMENSION 24cm 34cm 12cm DETAILED SPECIFICATION Twin/Twin XL Flat Sheet: 105 w. CARE For best results, machine wash warm with like colors. COLOURS red blue green";

    String[] keys = {"DIMENSIONS", "DETAILED SPECIFICATION", "CARE", "COLOURS"};

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {

        String subString = "";
        if(index + 1 < keys.length) {
            int start = str.indexOf(keys[index] + " ") > 0 ? str.indexOf(keys[index] + " ") + keys[index].length() : str.indexOf(keys[index]);
            int end = str.indexOf(keys[index + 1]);
            if(start < 0 || end < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            subString = str.substring(start, end);
        }  else {
            subString = str.substring(str.indexOf(keys[index] + " "));
        }
        map.put(keys[index], subString);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the trying but dimensions are not getting saved in the map here.

Comment: Also if one of the key value pair is not present in the string, it is giving wrong result.

Comment: Just add "space" after key[index] and try

Comment: No its not working Shubham